# Leveling up online in Call of Duty: Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a fast way to get built up in Black Ops multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/whats-a-fast-way-to-get-built-up-in-black-ops-multiplayer)

Aside from the standard kills, winning matches, and using the same gun, what other ways will help you level up quicker online? When starting out, spending a few hours going up about 10 levels is nice and quick, but obviously nearing higher levels tends to sap a lot of time just for one promotion.

Didn't know if focusing on Challenges yielded better benefits than say constantly playing one type of match using the same few guns all the time.

Comment: Similar thread, if not almost the same: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10774/4182

Comment: ah thanx Bora, I did a quick search but couldn't find anything, appreciate the link