# What's the best, fastest way to rank up in Modern Warfare 3?  Depth or breadth?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Put very simply, is it more effective to focus on a broad set of challenges or perform several challenges in the same category?  For example, should I try to complete challenges with all the assault rifles or max out a single

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Focus on what you're good at!  If you are decent with most guns breadth is a great way to gain some quick levels.  Otherwise, use you're favorite gun and mop up the competition.

### Ranking up like a bad ***

**Gun Challenges**

Its also worth noting that more kills trumps completing challenges almost every time. What I mean by this is don't spend your time on a gun you suck with for experience. The opportunity cost of the kills you didn't get by using a crappy gun greatly outweighs the experience you gain from the challenges. By using a better gun you'll get more kill streaks which in turn gives you more experience and more kill streaks, and kill streaks also give experience!

**Kill Streaks**

Pick low kill streak rewards (as these provide you with extra experience every time you call them in) and try and get these often (hardline?). Keep in mind that getting an osprey gunner, while awesome provides THE SAME AMOUNT of experience as calling in a uav. By using low achievable kill streaks you will gain more experience by using the kill streak, gain more experience by challenges for the kill streak, and gain more experience by the kills you get when your kill streaks are up! Most of this game is about snowballing your momentum.

**Equipment**

One of the most often over looked ways of gaining experience. Not utilizing your equipment is bottom line a wasted opportunity. Don't think of throwing that flash bang grenade as -wasted- think of it as utilized. Every time you die with out throwing your flashbang you have wasted the opportunity to potentially save your life, potentially get a kill, and work on your equipment challenges. Wasted equipment is sad equipment. Utilized equipment is just one more layer of the snowball (see above)

Keeping these things in mind will help you level up faster, but its worth reiterating the most important part of this description. If you are using crappy perks and crappy guns to get challenges YOU WILL LOSE EXPERIENCE. The smarter you play (low kill streaks, great perks, great gun) the more kills you'll get which will lead to more kill streaks which will lead to more challenges which will lead to more experience!

**Thesis**

Now this seemed like a long detour to the point, but here it is. If you play better you will level up faster.

As far as an 'optimum route' this really depends on how you play. Ever had a friend argue with you for hours about how 'their xyz' is always the best but it just doesn't work for you? You and I will be significantly better with different guns and different perks, but you wont find whats 'optimized' for you until you try it. Try it out on a 'test' class while you get a feel for which guns and perk choices fit your play style best. Want to try a new gun? Go for it. Just make sure you always dedicate a class to something you know you can kick ass with. That will give you a fall back while you investigate which perks and guns are good for you!

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't look like it pertains to MW3 specifically - there's no cash system outside of survival.

Comment: @Ian Very good catch!  This was taken from a black ops post I made a while back, but most of it still applied (especially with a little tailoring) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/whats-a-fast-way-to-get-built-up-in-black-ops-multiplayer/10780#10780

Comment: You seem to be talking about Black Ops near the end, but it's practically the same. (The Famas was removed in MW3). One point I'd like to make though. Even though launching an Osprey gunner gives you the same XP as a UAV, you may get 15 kills with it.. And also sometimes you have to play with a crap gun because it's not good until you get a certain proficiency and certain attachment. Don't be so short-sighted :)

Comment: @Earlz agreed the Osprey gunner gives 15 kills, but you will get so many more uav's to Osprey gunners (because 2-3 kills is so much easier then 17) that in the end you will have gotten much more experience from rolling with uav's.  I couldn't agree more with the proficiency and attachment, but he was specifically talking about leveling up as fast as possible.

Comment: One thing I've found useful wrt to the using a gun/perk/attachment you're good with is if that item is unlocked later on in the level progression (Level 30 or 40+) consider unlocking it with an Unlock Gear when you next prestige so you can start using it right away and level it up and complete related challenges earlier and just generally get you the class you want without having to grind through a bunch of levels with guns, perks and items you dislike.

Answer (score 2):

early on there is a lot of easy xp to be picked up from breadth, but as you get further in, the bulk of your xp will come from kills and kill streaks at which point you should specialize.

Answer (score 2):

This is silly, I run and gun and therefore poeple must realise SnD is crap for me, I get 30+ kills in Domination and get 2,000+ points when playing Kill Confirmed by getting tags.

It is all about the kills with **multiple** weapons, by thisIi mean attacking all challenges.  Get 300 and 500 kills with a gun - each will give you 10,000 - then move onto the next gun. Dont forget about perks, 10,000xp to be had via SOD, Scavenger etc.

Proficiencies provide opportunities as well, 300 kills/tasks nets you 10,000xp.

You really do need to be checking challenges during every intermission to see which is close and which to go for next.

Answer (score 1):

I say play search and destroy with low killstreaks and hardline. 500 xp for every kill!!!

And get challenges. there is a lot of objective/bomb based challenges in search and destroy that will give you a lot of xp.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to level up in MW3 is to play team games and complete daily challenges, in addition to other challenges in the barracks area.

Daily challenges award an exta 1000 xp

Many other challenges, (gun challenges, etc) award high points : 250 - 1000 xp.

You can effectively get a score of 5000, 10,000 or more in a game if you are aware of challenges like "kill an opponent in mid air" "plant one bomb", etc... all ones I got in one game of sabotage.

So we lost the game, but I got a score of over 5000 xp by completing 3 challenges and killing a bunch of people.

PLAY SABOTAGE
These games can get extended quite a bit and you change sides in every game.
You can rack up a ton of kills, as people come in waves and waves trying to move into positions. Players re-spawn and the game is much much longer than FFA or TDM.

Play Kill Confirmed
KC is great as you can get 500 xp for picking up your own tags, denying kills via picking up team mates tags, or picking up tags of a downed enemy.
This is all in addition to points awarded for kills, streaks, and wining a match.

Typically the larger a game - Team or big team AND longer a game, like sabotage, demolition, etc... the more points each game provides. I recommend using the support kill streak packages so your kill count doesn't reset with each death. And there are some epic kill streaks for support.

Comment: Im pretty sure you only get 250 for picking up your own dog tags, second, support killstreaks are for the people that cant get a 2 or 3 killsreak without dying, and ffa is good only if your good because i get 3000 every game.

Comment: I'm recommending the paths of least frustration for new players. If he isn't great, I don't recommend FFA.

Answer (score 1):

One thing can potentially get lost with this sort of levelling system: the fun.  There's little point in playing if you're not enjoying it.

Bear with me here.  What has this got to do with levelling?  Well, in my view it's more profitable, purely in terms of fun, to focus on the kinds of things you like.

For example, I hate vanilla MP and I only play hardcore.  Sure, there's stuff I can't do in hardcore, like use Recon or do its challenges (almost every explosion is fatal in HC) but I'd rather be playing the sort of game I enjoy than spending any time on modes that are no fun for me.  I generally suck at sniping in all CoD games, and the LMGs are a touch redundant in hardcore; therefore, I stuck to SMGs and shotguns where I could, and ARs otherwise, on the way to get to 80.  Now I'm at 80, I'm working on the snipers and the LMGs.  My point is, level with what you enjoy doing and find you're good at, not what cold hard maths says is easiest.

Hardcore itself is a good way to level, as secondary weapons are much more deadly and since they only have ten levels, it's not too hard to max them, along with all the challenges that helps with.  Also, it's good fun owning riflemen and machinegunners with your trusty revolver =)  Bear in mind the increased lethality of everything makes things that require X number of kills to complete, rather than levelling through XP, easier to get, particularly with low damage weapons.  Assuming, of course, you can adjust to the extra vulnerability of only having 30 HP max.

Finally, don't prestige.  Really, what's the point?  Lose everything you spent your time on, for what?  More titles and emblems?  An extra class, which you don't need as you can edit your classes in the intermission?  That way lies grind and drudgery.  I prestiged once in Black Ops to get a sixth class (no intermissions, at least not on PC, so worthwhile on paper) and at one point I found myself on a Nuketown only server, flinging semtex outside the map just so I could pick up another with Scavenger in order to do a pro challenge (kill X people with a resupplied 'nade) and unlock a pro perk.  That wasn't fun.  That was just grind.  I didn't prestige again.  Don't do it - that's my advice.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a gun you like a lot and continue to use that gun 'til you max it out and get all of the challenges for it.  It works really well for getting you kills since you're used to the weapon, and because you get level up challenges. I used Pkp Pecheneg for 25 levels.  Then the Scar for 6 more.

Answer (score 1):

Search and Destroy things. Time spent on the game is experience gained.

1 plant gives 1000xp, 2000xp when double XP is present.

150 seconds a round, with a maximum of 7 rounds.

Unless you are terrible, SnD is the quickest way to level up.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I have double XP and running and I'm getting 2000 points a kill in SnD. I average around 9 kills a game, so with an average of 2 headshots a game (which is 4000 xp a kill!), I rack up around 22,000 to 24,000 xp per game for kills only. Each diffuse or plant I get is another 2000, and match bonuses add up as well. In the end I get 30,000 xp per game in total around.

Answer (score -1):

Drop zone is currently the fastest way to rank up. TmarT has a video on the stats of it, because i don't feel like explaining it all fully. But I will say some easy advice... Pick a tank w/ str & conditioning, blast shield, Yellow perk doesn't matter, I like sitrep or dead silence so they don't hear you trot in. trophy system helps, so does tac inserts. I lean toward Trophy.

Comment: Link to videos maybe?

Answer (score -1):

i know some ways how-to first play a good game mode when you get use to it play more and then you will get use to everything and then when your good at everymode and your prestige 78 or whatever play kill confirmed and try not to camp rush and run past corners (Or somone will be camping) sooo get good kills and this is the thing you need to use everytime you get a kill and your about to die run back in a safe area so then that guy comes back and you will get that kill thats what i do so just don't spend your time camping somone will jump past you and kill you one more thing use the gun you get every kill with then you should be on rank 80 sooo thats all i know:D